# Encrypt Data by using Digital signature in PKCS7 format with base 64 encoding

Tags: php, pkcs#7

We are writing to validate user data by using API. For validating purpose, i need to pass two variable in post method call and Two variables are data and signature. So Digital signature of data in PKCS7 format with base 64 encoding.

For encryption they gave pem file to encrypt the data to generate signature in PKCS7 format with base 64 encoding.

So kindly advise me how to do this encryption and i am doing this project in PHP.

Also i have tried with following code but no results

```
$data = 'Test Data';
$key = file_get_contents("certificate.pem");
$fp = fopen("msg.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
openssl_pkcs7_encrypt("msg.txt", "enc.txt", $key,[]);
```

Output:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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==
```

But it is not accepted from remote. Please help me

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure whether you want to sign, encrypt, or verify. And what does "no results" mean? What was the error you where getting?

Comment: @DanFromGermany i have added sample output on question

Comment: @DanFromGermany Please refer the output and advise me how to do encryption and what are things required for data encryption.

Comment: Do you need to encrypt the data or make a signature? It's two different things. You talk about both. See `openssl_pkcs7_sign()`

Comment: @DanFromGermany i need to generate signature but they gave only certificate file only. Can you advise me how to generate signature?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your pem file contains the certificate + a private key and you need to make a signature instead of encrypt the data.

Use therefore `openssl_pkcs7_sign()` instead of encrypt.

Comment: Yes I need to generate signature but they gave only certificate(.cer) file only. Can you advise me how to generate signature?